# Open/Save SWT Text Object with ObjectOutput/InputStream

Tags: java, swt

I'm trying to open/save a Text Object from SWT with the ObjectOutputStream. But it doesn't work. Have anybody an idea, why?

```
public static void read(String fileName, Text textField) {
    int c=0;
    try {
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileName));

        c= in.readInt();

        textField = (Text) in.readObject();

        in.close();
    } 
    catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void write(String fileName, Text textField) {
    int c = 1;
    try {
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fileName));
        out.writeInt(c);
        out.writeObject((Text)textField);

        out.close();

    } 
    catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The Error which appears on the console when i save:

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at FileIO.write(FileIO.java:42)
    at SelectionAdapterSave.widgetSelected(SelectionAdapterSave.java:29)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1057)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4170)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3759)
    at Editor.open(Editor.java:230)
    at EditorMain.main(EditorMain.java:6)
```

and this when i try to open the file, what i saved before:

```
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at FileIO.write(FileIO.java:42)
    at SelectionAdapterSave.widgetSelected(SelectionAdapterSave.java:29)
    ... 7 more
```

Comment: Please tell us more what happens when this code is run

Comment: Is it enough, or do you need more information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use `ObjectOutputStream` on objects which implement `Serializable`. The SWT `Text` class does not implement this.

A SWT `Text` class contains all sorts of objects which depend on the native UI code, there is no way this can be saved and loaded again.

Comment: What do you advise to me to do that? Is there another possibility to save/load it?

Comment: Explain why you want to save the Text object, saving a UI control like this is unusual.

Comment: I have to write a small Editor with SWT, and when i want to save a file it should save the Text, Color, Font etc.. and when i open a file with the editor the same...

Comment: You will have to extract all that information from the control and save it in some format that you invent. Maybe using DataOutputStream.

Comment: So i take all the informtion that i want, put it in a string and write it in a file? and load the information in same way from the file and put it in that Text Object?

Comment: Yes, something like that